# JQuery adding class

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to add a class on the following div using JQuery and I don't know what I am doing incorrectly.

```
<div class="flash alert">You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.</div>
```

I want to remove the alert class and add the classes alert-message, and error. I have been using the following code which hasn't been working:

```
$('div flash alert').removeclass('.alert').addClass('.alertMessage .error');
```

I can't edit the css directly, if I could go that path I would.

Here is a jsfiddle link of exactly what I have written. It works in the jsfiddle but not on my page: http://jsfiddle.net/uR3gz/2/ Here is what it looks like on my page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMIbk.jpg

Notes: I am using rails with devise and I am trying to get rid of the default alert message.

Note I got the whole thing to work by wrapping it in an anonymous function like so:

```
$(function() {
  $('div.flash.alert').removeClass('alert').addClass('alert-message error');
});
```

Comment: Try removing the DIV from:   $('div flash alert').    Just use $('flash alert').

Comment: You don't need to use the '.' notation when using the class name in jQuery methods like addClass or removeClass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of issues with this.

```
$('div flash alert')
```

That selects `alert` elements inside `flash` elements inside `div` elements. I think you want `div.flash.alert`.

```
.removeclass('.alert')
```

You need `removeClass` (capitals matter) and `'alert'`. You don't need the dot since it's not part of the class name.

```
.addClass('.alertMessage .error');
```

Again, you don't need the dots.

---

So the final solution may look like this:

```
$('div.flash.alert').removeClass('alert').addClass('alertMessage error');
```

---

So, on top of all your syntax problems, you were running the code before the document was parsed, so the element you were trying to select didn't exist yet. The solution to this is to use an event listener on the `document`'s `ready` event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){...});
$(function(){...}); // shortcut for the above code
```

Comment: I have added the following $('div.flash.alert').removeClass('alert').addClass('alertMessage error'); and it still does not work.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Can you show us an example? jsfiddle.net is good for this.

Comment: It is valid javascript but it won't work in my rails app for some reason. When I have added the line to my main javascript file, as written and load the page with the resulting javascript it does not change the css at all. I still get the same div with no changes. It literally does nothing to change the file.

Comment: @demondeac11 There could be any number of reasons. Psychic debugging, when we can't see the code, is kind of tricky.

Comment: added a jsfiddle link, will add images to what the browser looks like for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('div .flash .alert').removeclass('alert').addClass('alertMessage error');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.flash.alert').removeClass('alert').addClass('alertMessage error');
```

Note this changes all divs with the class="flash alert", if you want to change a specific div it might be better to give it an id, then you can select it with `$('#myId')`